# struts2: avoiding hardcode in struts tags, jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, hardcode

When using struts2 I can access my session attributes inside struts2 tags using OGNL expression like this:

```
#session['object_key']
```

The problem is that I use this expression on different pages, every time hardcoding that 'object_key' string. Is there any way I can use any sort of named constant, so that I can easily change the key used to store my object in session map?

Comment: you mean to say declaring a static constant inside your action class?? you can declare a method and can set value inside that method,just try something @vs@someMethod() where vs refer to value stack

Comment: @umesh I'm looking for any solution that helps to avoid hardcoding the key. Please post an answer if you have one.

Comment: see answer of Dave was about to write the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use a static constant; there are several options for how to go about this.

*Default, access using fully-qualified name:*

```
<s:property value="#session[@app.Constants@OBJECT_KEY]" />
```

For details, see [Accessing static properties](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties) in the [OGNL Basics](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html) page.

Another trick is to set up an interceptor that pushes a class of constants onto the value stack, with constant-"looking" getters. You could do the same in an action as well, for example, a base action class could be used.

Then all that's needed in the JSP is this:

```
${session[OBJECT_KEY]}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave. What do you think about the idea to create separate jsp file, where all needed constants are put into struts2 variable like this: `<s:set name="SESSION_NAME" value="#session[@app.Constants@OBJECT_KEY]" />`  and then include this jsp and use your second example syntax but without messing with interceptor stack?

Comment: Wrong code sample there, must be `<s:set name="SESSION_NAME" value="@app.Constants@OBJECT_KEY" />`

Comment: @pavel_kazlou I think creating a JSP to do that is a waste of time, and additional, unnecessary work, when compared to more reasonable solutions.